# React redux how to use getState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am fetching data from the `Firebase Real-time database` and storing it into my redux state. How can I create an action that will get the latest and most up to date state after the initial call?

```
const getIds = (state) => state.notes.activeNotes;

export const getUserNotes = (currentUserId) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  getFromFirebase(`/Notes/${currentUserId}/`, (response) => {
    var ids = Object.keys(response)
      dispatch(setNoteIds(ids)); //should dispatch ids something like this [1,2,3,4,5]
  })

  const test= getIds(getState());
  console.log(test); //current output []
}

Expected output: [1,2,3,4,5]
Actual output: []
```

Comment: do you want the api to get called for fetching the latest data?

Comment: getFromFirebase() function populates activeNotes of Ids. Once populated I want to be able to read the post populate the state so instead of it being an empty array it will contain Ids fetched from getFromFirebase()

Comment: It looks like the `getFromFirebase` is async which means you can await the result then set dispatch then retrieve your state again

Comment: @tmhao2005 Would it be possible for you to demonstrate an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the function `getFromFirebase` returns a promise then you can switch your method to async as following:

```js
export const getUserNotes = (currentUserId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  // wait the result dispatched
  await getFromFirebase(`/Notes/${currentUserId}/`, (response) => {
    var ids = Object.keys(response)
      dispatch(setNoteIds(ids)); //should dispatch ids something like this [1,2,3,4,5]
  })
  
  const test= getIds(getState());
}
```

Or if the `getFromFirebase` is not a promise, you can wrap it up by a promise:

```js
export const getUserNotes = (currentUserId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  // wrap in a promise
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    getFromFirebase(`/Notes/${currentUserId}/`, (response) => {
      var ids = Object.keys(response)
        dispatch(setNoteIds(ids)); //should dispatch ids something like this [1,2,3,4,5]
        resolve();
    })
  })
  
  const test= getIds(getState())
}
```

Comment: Ah, it wasn't returning a promise. The 2nd solution seems to have done the job!